# Validate a nested object with Yup in Formik

Tags: formik, yup

I am trying to validate a nested object in a Formik form with Yup. I am also using the formik-antd library (just mappings between formik and antd).

After I select an option the Select component, I get this error msg:
`parent.id is a required field`.

Here's my Yup schema:

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    parent: Yup.object().shape(
        {
            id: Yup.string().required()
        }
    )
})
```

And my form:

```
import { FormItem, TreeSelect } from '@jbuschke/formik-antd'

<React.Fragment>
    <FormItem name='parent.id'>
        <TreeSelect
            name='parent.id'
            style={{ width: '100%', marginBottom: '.5rem', marginTop: '.5rem' }}
            value={selectedWbsComponent}
            dropdownStyle={{ maxHeight: 400, overflow: 'auto' }}
            treeData={treeData}
            placeholder='Select parent WBS component'
            treeDefaultExpandAll
            onChange={onChange}
        />
    </FormItem>
</React.Fragment>
```

Comment: unclear on whats not working, are you saying you get error message pop up while you are doing select?

Comment: Yes, just after I selected a value, the error msg appears under the field to tell me it's not valid.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this please?

Comment: I don't remember and I don't think so. I'm using Antd, which comes with form and validation, and thats good enough to not use yet another library. Good luck!